# BeautifulSoup python: Get the text with no tags and get the adjacent links

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the movie titles and links for it from this [site](https://tamilrockerrs.ch)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get


link = "https://tamilrockerrs.ch"
r = get(link).content
#r = open('json.html','rb').read()
b = BeautifulSoup(r,'html5lib')
a = b.findAll('p')[1]
```

But the problem is there is no tag for the titles. I can't extract the titles and if I could do that how can I bind the links and title together.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you give a couple of examples of the output you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You can find `title` and `link` by this way.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests    

url= "http://tamilrockerrs.ch"

response= requests.get(url)

data = response.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

data = soup.find_all('div', {"class":"title"})

for film in data:
    print("Title:", film.find('a').text) # get the title here 
    print("Link:",  film.find('a').get("href")) #get the link here
```

Comment: Sorry that's not what I wanted did you check the link and you will find there multiple links to the movie but the movies isn't having a tag it, the movie name either comes after a span tag or br tag and its confusing for me.I hope you understand me.