# Python regex: text between <a> tag

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I know I got BeautifulSoup, But I want to try my own.

[Regex I've been working on](https://pythex.org/?regex=(%3C%2Fa%3E%7C(%3Cbr(%2F%3E%7C%3E)))(%5Cs.*%7C%5Cw.*)&test_string=%3Cbr%3EThis%20Text%20needed%0A%3Ca%3Eunwanted%20text%3C%2Fa%3E%0A%3Cbr%2F%3E%0AThis%20text%20needed%0A%3Ca%20%3Eunwanted%20text%3C%2Fa%3E%0A%20This%20text%20needed%0A%3Ca%3Eunwanted%20text%3C%2Fa%3E%0A%3Cbr%3Ethis%20text%20needed&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

```
<br>This Text needed
<a>unwanted text</a>
<br/>
This text needed
<a >unwanted text</a>
 This text needed
<a>unwanted text</a>
<br>this text needed
```

What I have come up with:

```
(</a>|(<br(/>|>)))(\s.*|\w.*)
```

I want to match the `This text needed` but one of them isn't matching.

Comment: What do you need to get in the end?

Comment: @Эдуард    `This text needed`

Comment: Im new to regex so sorry

Comment: On the second line it detects `</a>` and `<br/>` from the third line but not after that

Comment: ok, now I will write an example

Comment: And what should I add to match the text to my regex and thanks

Comment: example for php: [`~(?:<br/?>\s*|</?a>\s*)\K[\pL\s]+(?:(?=<a[^>]*>)|$)~`](https://regex101.com/r/9SgJC2/3)

Comment: *"I know I got BeautifulSoup, But I want to try my own."* No. Use BeautifulSoup. There is a reason why people keep recommending it.

Comment: Also see: [Why it's not possible to use regex to parse HTML/XML: a formal explanation in layman's terms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6751105/18771).

Comment: @Tomalak https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55020485/beautifulsoup-python-get-the-text-with-no-tags-and-get-the-adjacent-links/55021005#55021005 then help me with this

Comment: @Tomalak answer that question if you can and so I don't Have to create new regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this way with **lookahead negative** and **lookbehind positive**,

```
(?<!<a>)This Text needed(?!<\/a>)
```

**DEMO:** https://regex101.com/r/RT5LZu/1

Comment: Recommending regex for HTML is an immediate downvote.

Comment: @Tomalak sorry sir I didn't know that

Comment: It's giving genuinely bad advice to people who don't know any better, and this is the exact opposite of what Stack Overflow should do.

Comment: I got your back @Always Sunny